# Python : Issue with POST data in requests

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I am working on a python(3.6.X) script that will connect to Hashicorp vault and copy some data and then also create a policy for that data.
I tested the flow using curl commands and it works. However when I try to convert that in to python requests , I get unable to parse JSON error.( I used curl.trillworks.com to convert from curl to python requests)

Below is my curl command and the requests module.

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token:s.Newtoken" --request PUT --data '{ "policy": "path \"/automation/data/demo.na.vwg\" { capabilities = [ \"read\"] }" }' https://test-vault.com/v1/sys/policies/acl/demo.policy
```

Python code:

```
headers = {
    'X-Vault-Token': 's.Newtoken',
}

data = {
  '{ "policy": "path \\"/automation/data/demo.na.vwg\\" { capabilities ': ' [ \\"read\\"] }" }'
}


response = requests.post('https://test-vault.com/v1/sys/policies/acl/demo.policy', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False )

response.json()

{'errors': ["failed to parse JSON input: invalid character '%' looking for beginning of value"]}
```

The error points that there is something wrong with the json format, I validated the json in json validator and it seems to be good.

Need to figure out how to convert the data from curl `--data '{ "policy": "path \"/automation/data/demo.na.vwg\" { capabilities = [ \"read\"] }" }'` to json(dictionary) with out errors

Can somebody please assist me with the conversion,the structure and can point out the error in the code I am using. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  The workaround I came up with in CURL was to drop the JSON to a file and upload the actual JSON file itself. If there is a better way to do this I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Json initial was `{'data': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}` and needed to be converted to following expected format `{"data": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}}`

Code :

```
requests.post(URL1, headers={"X-Vault-Token":"s. Newtoken"}, data=json.dumps(body1))
```